# unwinding the definition of $H_i(KU)$ as a map of spectra $\mathbb{S}^i \to HZ \wedge KU$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy

I asked this on mathstackexchange but didn't get any response (or many views) so I'm asking it here, although clearly it belongs over there.

In the answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117684/are-spectra-really-the-same-as-cohomology-theories) question on mathoverflow, it says:
"The integral homology group $H_i(KU)$ is the direct limit of

$$\dots \to H_{2n+i}(BU)\to H_{2n+2+i}(BU)\to\dots,"$$

My question is why? Here is my understanding: Given two spectra $E, X$, I believe the definition of the homology group $E_i(X)$ is 
$$E_i(X):=[\Sigma^i \mathbb{S}, E \wedge X]_{stable}=colim_j[S^{i+j}, (E \wedge X)_j]$$ 
where the square brackets denote homotopy classes of maps. 
In the case at hand, $E=H\mathbb{Z}$ (or maybe $E=\Sigma H\mathbb{Z}$?) is the spectrum whose $n$th space is the Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(\mathbb{Z}, n)$, and $X=KU$ is the spectrum whose $n$ space is either $BU \times \mathbb{Z}$ or $BU$, depending on if $n$ is even or odd, respectively. I have no idea what the $n$th space of $HZ \wedge KU$ is, since I am  confused by smash product of spectra. I'm still learning how to best think of maps between spectra.

Comment: On one hand, homology can actually be define as such a direct limit. On the other hand as you say, it can be defined as homotopy of $E \wedge X$. I believe it is in an old paper of Whitehead that he proved they are equal. This equivalence is shown but not proven in Adams blue book.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll define a *naive prespectrum* to be a system of spaces $X_i$ with maps $\Sigma X_i\to X_{i+1}$.  That seems to be what you want to work with, but it is not technically very satisfactory.  However, if $\mathcal{C}$ is one of the fancier categories of spectra, then one can define $FX$ to be the homotopy colimit in $\mathcal{C}$ of the objects $\Sigma^{-i}\Sigma^\infty X_i$, and that will give an object of $\mathcal{C}$ that has the homotopy type that you want.  From this perspective, the real point is that $FX \wedge FY$ is the homotopy colimit of the diagram of objects $\Sigma^{-i-j}\Sigma^\infty X_i\wedge Y_j$, and that colimit can be broken down in three different ways:

- Take the colimit over $i$ first, then the colimit over $j$
- Take the colimit over $j$ first, then the colimit over $i$
- Take the colimit of the diagonal terms $\Sigma^{-2i}\Sigma^\infty X_i\wedge Y_i$.

It is a fairly formal argument to show that these are all the same, and so 
$$ X_nY = \text{colim}_{i,j}\pi_{n+i+j}(X_i\wedge Y_j) = 
 \text{colim}_i \pi_{n+2i}(X_i\wedge Y_i) = 
 \text{colim}_i X_{n+i}Y_i = \text{colim}_i Y_{n+i}X_i.
$$

If you want to work exclusively with naive prespectra, you can use the "handicrafted smash product" 
$$ (X\wedge Y)_{2i} = X_i\wedge Y_i $$
$$ (X\wedge Y)_{2i+1} = X_i\wedge Y_{i+1} $$
It is unpleasant to prove any properties based on this definition, but it is adequate for the calculation that you asked about.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying. I guess I should change what I first think about when I see $X_nY$, and instead of $[\Sigma^n \mathbb{S}, X \wedge Y]$, I should think $colim_i X_{n+i}Y_i$